# Can we access the icons used by the BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE browse window?

Tags: c++, mfc, modal-dialog

On one of my property sheets I have two `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl` objects.

One of them is for selecting a local folder on the computer. So I have used the following style in `OnInitDialog`:

```
m_BrowseLocalBackupFolder.EnableFolderBrowseButton(nullptr, BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE);
```

The popup window when browsing for the folder looks like this:

[image: Browse for Folder]

My other control uses my own class `CRemoteFTPFolderSelect` which is derived from the `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl`. This is because I need to display a remote folder listing via FTP. I am using FluentFTP via my C# DLL wrapper to achieve this. My `OnBrowse` method:

```
void CRemoteFTPFolderSelect::OnBrowse()
{
    if (theApp.MSAToolsInterface().ConnectToFTP(m_strHostname, m_strUsername, m_strPassword))
    {
        CBrowseFolderFTP dlgBrowse(this);
        CString strRemoteBackupFolder;

        GetWindowText(strRemoteBackupFolder);

        if (strRemoteBackupFolder != _T(""))
            dlgBrowse.SetSelectedFolder(strRemoteBackupFolder);

        if (dlgBrowse.DoModal() == IDOK)
        {
            dlgBrowse.GetSelectedFolder(strRemoteBackupFolder);
            SetWindowText(strRemoteBackupFolder);

            CMFCPropertyPage* pParent = (CMFCPropertyPage*)GetParent();
            if (pParent)
            {
                CWnd* pWnd = pParent->GetDlgItem(IDC_BUTTON_APPLY);
                if (pWnd != nullptr)
                    pWnd->EnableWindow(TRUE);
            }
        }

        theApp.MSAToolsInterface().DisconnectFromFTP();
    }
}
```

I have had to use my own dialog resource and at the moment it looks like this:

[image: Browse for FTP Folder]

At the moment I am creating the image list like this:

```
SHGetFileInfo( 
    _T("Doesn't matter"), 
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY, 
    &sfi, sizeof sfi, 
    SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_SMALLICON | SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES); 
m_imgList.Add(sfi.hIcon);

SHGetFileInfo( 
    _T("Doesn't matter"), 
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY, 
    &sfi, sizeof sfi, 
    SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_OPENICON | SHGFI_SMALLICON | SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES); 
m_imgList.Add(sfi.hIcon);

m_treeFTP.SetImageList(&m_imgList, TVSIL_NORMAL );
```

Is it possible to get icons similar to those used by the `m_BrowseLocalBackupFolder.EnableFolderBrowseButton(nullptr, BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE)` browse window for the + / - images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the theme of the tree view using [SetWindowTheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-setwindowtheme) API:

In order to set it to "Explorer" like view, use this code:

```
SetWindowTheme(hwndTreeView, L"Explorer", NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this out!